# [Python] How to get distance from PointCloud2

Tags: ros, python, kinect, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys. I follow [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/115136/python-pointcloud2-read_points-problem/) question to extract informations (distance) from PointCloud2 with kinect and ros. I need to get distance of [x,y] pixel in real world.

[This](https://pastebin.com/TViLsLcA) is my code

When I run it, I get, for variable "int_data", three fields. But I do not know what they are. They seems like a distance, but I am not sure.

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1501099449.999255] int_data (0.008157123811542988, 0.006674010306596756, 0.8540000319480896)
```

Can anyone explain in detail what they are?

**Edit:**
This is the code that is being linked to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from roslib import message
import rospy
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2, PointField

#listener
def listen():
    rospy.init_node('listen', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/camera/depth/points", PointCloud2, callback_kinect)
    rospy.spin()

def callback_kinect(data) :
    # pick a height
    height =  int (data.height / 2)
    # pick x coords near front and center
    middle_x = int (data.width / 2)
    # examine point
    middle = read_depth (middle_x, height, data)
    # do stuff with middle


def read_depth(width, height, data) :
    # read function
    if (height >= data.height) or (width >= data.width) :
        return -1
    data_out = pc2.read_points(data, field_names=None, skip_nans=False, uvs=[[width, height]])
    int_data = next(data_out)
    rospy.loginfo("int_data " + str(int_data))
    return int_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listen()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267471/%5Bpython%5D-how-to-get-distance-from-pointcloud2/) by [sabruri1](https://answers.ros.org/users/31357/sabruri1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-05**:
@l4ncelot, @sabruri1
I have faced an issue, i have used the code and insted of depth of camera, i subscribed to /velodyne_points.
Now the issue is that when we have uvs=[[width, height]], the output is as follows (x,y,z):

```
[INFO] [1659697854.053652]: int_data (-11.6488037109375, -3.0516631603240967, -1.9072492122650146)
```

and when i consider uvs=[ ], the output is as follows:

```
[INFO] [1659697107.795461]: int_data (5.123467445373535, 1.491416573524475, -1.0372377634048462)
```

why the values are different? what is the meaning of uvs? what is the difference between uvs=[[width, height]] and uvs=[ ]  ???

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it depends on `fields` member of `sensors_msgs/PointCloud2` message described [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) in `read_points` function.

With `field_name=None` option you read all field names as described [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/point__cloud2_8py_source.html). In your case it seems like default configuration which should be classical cartesian coordinate system x, y, z. Have a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview) at section 1.3 **Common PointCloud2 field names**.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0